# Прибавить + 1 в MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
$done_users = $data['done_users']; // получаем кол-во юзеров из поля done_users
$done_users_sum = $done_users + 1; // прибавляем к done_users + 1

$db->query("UPDATE `qweqwe`.`tasks`
            SET `done_users` = '$done_users_sum'
            WHERE `tasks`.`id` = 8);
```

В случае, если одновременно этот запрос выполнится под 20 людьми, счётчик не залагает? Например вместо 20, запишет 21 или вообще 18?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$db->query("UPDATE `qweqwe`.`tasks`
            SET `done_users` = done_users + 1 
            WHERE `tasks`.`id` = 8);
```

добавляй хэш и не будет слетать

Answer (score 2):

А так не проще?

```
$db->query("UPDATE `qweqwe`.`tasks`
            SET `done_users` = `done_users` + 1
            WHERE `tasks`.`id` = 8");
```